# How to sort array by 3 columns by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I am trying to sort array by three columns. Below is my sample array. Sometime, the column can be null too, so I do a checking in my sort function. However, now I would like to sort the name first and then salary and then bonus. How can I achieve that?

```js
let employees = [
    {name: 'John', salary: 90000, bonus: 1000},
    {name: 'David', salary: 90000, bonus: 1200},
    {name: 'Ana', salary: 80000, bonus: 3000}
];

// Code for sorting salary first and then bonus:
function sort(a,b) {
  if (a.salary=== null && b.salary=== null ){
    return a.bonus- b.bonus;
  } 
  else if (a.salary!== null && b.salary=== null ){
    return -1;
  }
  else if (a.salary=== null && b.salary!== null){
    return 1;
  }else if (a.salary!== null && b.salary!== null){
    return a.salary- b.salary;
  }
  else {
    return 1;
  }
}

employees.sort(sort);
console.log(employees);
```

Comment: Just return the first non-zero compare or the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the first non-zero compare value.
 I've also made sure anything that's not a number would be sorted last, but if you are certain that you will only get a valid number or `null` then you can simplify the checks.

```js
const employees = [
    {name: 'Ana', salary: null, bonus: 3000},
    {name: 'Ana', salary: 80000, bonus: 3000},
    {name: 'Ana', salary: 70000, bonus: 3000},
    {name: 'Ana', salary: 70000, bonus: 1000}
];

employees.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) ||
    safeNumCompare(a.salary, b.salary) ||
    safeNumCompare(a.bonus, b.bonus);
});

console.log(employees);

function safeNumCompare(a, b) {
  const aValid = isValidNum(a), bValid = isValidNum(b);

  if (!(aValid || bValid)) return 0;
  if (!aValid) return 1;
  if (!bValid) return -1;
  return a - b;
}

function isValidNum(num) {
  return typeof num === 'number' && !isNaN(num);
}
```

Comment: When dealing with strings, use `string.localeCompare`. Its more safe and does your comparison

Answer (score 1):

There is an npm package called [lodash](https://lodash.com/). You can achieve your required functionality with their sortBy method.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let employees = [
    {name: 'John', salary: 90000, bonus: 1000},
    {name: 'David', salary: 90000, bonus: 1200},
    {name: 'Ana', salary: 80000, bonus: 3000}
];

const sortedArray = _.sortBy(employees, ['name', 'salary', 'bonus']);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Its not ideal to assume and use a library. Better to check with OP

Answer (score 1):

You can use this logic:

- Sort needs to return a numeric value. So you can use arithmetic operations.
- Your values can be `null`, so better to default.

  - `0` for ascending
  - `Infinity` for descending
- Perform `a - b` operation for ascending.
- For priority fall through, use `||` so that if first equation returns 0, it'll check for next priority

Note:

Above logic will sort in ascending of name then salary and then bonus. So if both users have same salary, then their bonus will be checked and sorted in that fashion.

```js
let employees = [{ name: 'John', salary: 90000, bonus: 1000 }, { name: 'David', salary: 90000, bonus: 1200}, { name: 'David',  salary: null,  bonus: 1200}, {  name: 'Ana',  salary: 80000,  bonus: 3000}, {  name: 'Ana',  salary: 80000,  bonus: null }];

function sort(a, b) {
  return (a.name.localeCompare(b.name)) ||
    ((a.salary || Infinity) - (b.salary || Infinity)) ||
    ((a.bonus || 0) - (b.bonus || 0));
}

employees.sort(sort);
console.log(employees);
```

As rightly suggested by [plalx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211528/plalx)

> He wanted nulls sorted last though and by name first as well.

Hence using `Infinity` for defaulting `salary`

Comment: He wanted nulls sorted last though and by name first as well.

Comment: @plalx in that case I'll use your idea of INFINITY

Comment: Yeah I wanted to use `Infinity`, but `0 || Infinity === Infinity` so in the end I went for a proper safe compare.

Comment: Note that the new implementation will sort `0` last because of the above comment. Just making sure you get the comment notification.

Comment: Thats a question for OP. Can a salary be 0? If yes, how is it different from `null`

Comment: Well, null generally means unknown where 0 would most likely mean charity work ;) Not sure how the OP wants to see it, but it feels odd that 0 gets sorted last IMO.